# stop action POST, in jquery whit two (' if ') necessarily. for validate my Form

Tags: jquery-templates, jquery

**i have, a click event live.**

To be necessary.  the validate a form i have a function extend.
 validatorForm. and  a length selector: $('#uploaded'). 
it's for  stoped Post Json. But the post is executed  i'm need help.. i'm great with the click live. because i'ts a live event.  when i have the  elements generating.

```
$('#regist').live("click",function(){   

  if(validateForm($('#fom_id'))){

    if($('#uploaded').text().length){
        $('#uploaded').removeClass('error');
        $('#form_id').append('<input type="text" class="hidden" name="email" value=" ' +  user.email  +'">');
        $('#form_id').append('<input type="text" class="hidden" name="upload" value=" ' +  upload  +'">');
        $('.hidden').hide();
        $.post(guide.php, {data: JSON.stringify($('#form_id').serializeJSON()), action: 'write'}, function(data){
            switch(data.status){
                case 1:
                    $.jGrowl(info_id,{header: 'save'});
                    $('#actions').dialog('close');
                    break
                case 1002:
                    console.log('error action');
            }
        },'json');

    }
    else{

        $('#uploaded').text('alert text').addClass('error');
    }
  }
  else{
    console.log('an error');
  }
});
```

the append and text change it's necessary for the functionally the form.

i help...

Comment: I don't understand the question...
Are there typos ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't really understand what you're asking but you have an error here, missing `r`:

```
if(validateForm($('#fom_id'))) // fom???
```

You're also missing a `;` after the first `break` and a missing `break` on the second `case`. Then, I would cache `$('#form_id')` since you use it many times.

Answer (score 0):

The [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) is a shortcut for [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), that only supports the `success` callback. If you need to add a callback for error, use instead:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: guide.php,
    data: {data: JSON.stringify($('#form_id').serializeJSON()), action: 'write'},
    success:function(data){
        $.jGrowl(info_id,{header: 'save'});
        $('#actions').dialog('close');
    },
    error:function(data){
        console.log('error action');
    },
    dataType:'json'
});
```

Comment: but not thought before thanks :) ... is for my school project.. see Demo http://swang.no-ip.org/swang ... thanks. for help me...